# Parse platform / MongoDB - create Parse pointer in stand alone script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform

I need to create a pointer object in a stand alone script the exact same way that parse server does. I have tried to manually create a string with the format ClassName$objectId Ive also tried to use parse.Object.extend and create the pointer but it doesnt work using standard mongo db inserts.

Comment: What do you mean by stand alone script? Can you share the code that you are currently using and why it is not working? Maybe I can try to help figure it out.

Comment: I mean within JavaScript alone (no Parse libs) I want to be able to create a Parse style pointer

Comment: You need to send a HTTP request like this [one](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#creating-objects) to create an object and send any pointer field in this format: `{ "__type": "Pointer", "className": "GameScore", "objectId": "Ed1nuqPvc" }`

Comment: Do you know is it possible to do with a raw mongo insert/update ?

Comment: Yes. But the format is different and it is tricky because you need to understand how Parse Server stores the different fields in the MongoDB. In the case of a pointer would be a string in the format `"ClassName$objectId"`, example: `"GameScore$Ed1nuqPvc"`

Comment: I actually tried that and it didnt work, I started to dig about the parse code too and i see they defined a custom mongo schema but i didnt get much further than that

Comment: If you want to share the code that you used and the problem you had with it, I can try to point out where the problem is.